# How did my dad lose the Blowpipe and Hidden Blade?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

My dad has been complaining about how he has lost the blowpipe for all the darts he keeps looting from bodies saying he had it in one mission then he lost it and has never been able to buy a new one or find it in his equipment, i've even seen him loot sleeping darts and berserk darts from bodies but since he can't use them it's always saying it's full.

When i saw him playing it on the weekend, where he is is apparently Edward got captured and some woman he liked died, when i saw my dad went to escape an assassin gave him a hidden blade to use during the escape however later on my dad had me help him locate some treasure and i found out he had no hidden blade.

I am wondering, did the game totally glitch up causing my dad to loose both weapons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "special" weapons like the hidden blades and the darts for the blowpipe are tied to the storyline; their availability depends upon your point of storyline progression.

- The hidden blades are acquired first within sequence 2, mission 3 ("Mister Walpole, I Presume").
- The blowpipe (together with the ability to acquire sleep and berserk darts) are first acquired within sequence 4, mission 4 ("Overrun & Outnumbered")
- The third dart type, the rope dart, is first acquired within sequence 11, mission 3 ("... Everything is permitted").

During storyline progression, you only loose your weapons and equipment once. This happens during sequence 8, mission 3 ("Marooned"). After finishing this mission, all equipment is re-acquired automatically.

Both signature weapons can not be bought, since they are acquired solely during storyline progression. Only the equipment for the blowpipe (individual darts) can be bought at general stores or crafted with animal bones.

Should you not have access to these weapons within the above-mentioned mission ranges, this is outside of the intensions of the game development and most likely some sort of bug / glitch.

Hope this helps.